# change resolution of picture according to its size

Tags: android, image, bitmap, resolution

I'm writing an app that uses the phone's camera to take a picture, and then display it. The problem is, for phones that have high-res cameras,  this caused the app to crash, so I lowered the resolution using isSampleSize, which solved this issue. But now I have a problem with phones that have lower resolution cameras - the picture has terrible quality. Is there any way to check what the image memory consumption is, and according to that decide whether I want to lower the quality or not?

Answer (score 0):

To rescale my picture, because I had a limitaion in the image height, I used the code below to resize it. But i didnt wan't to resize the bmp unless it was above my height requirement, hope you can use it. (Used a stream to get my pictures in)

```
                if (stream != null) {
                img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, o);
                float imgHeight = (float) img.getHeight();
                Display display = ((WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(
                        Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
                float displayHeight = (float) (display.getHeight()-50);
                if(imgHeight>displayHeight) {
                    float scaleFactor = displayHeight/imgHeight;
                    img = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(img, (int)(img.getWidth()*scaleFactor), (int)(imgHeight*scaleFactor), false);
                }
                saveBitmap(new File(getSdPath() + location), img);
            }
```

Comment: my problem is not with the height, I want the image to always be the same size. I need to change the resolution if the memory consumption is too high

Comment: Think I saw something about it here on stackoverflow, but haven't played with that part myself.